# Unable to host multiple sites on same domain in django using Apache2.4

Tags: django, windows, apache

I am new to Django and I was working on an application in which I need to host three different Django projects on the same domain name. I have tried all the ways that I get on the internet. Please help me with the solution and how I can do this. I am using Django 2.2 version on windows. Each project has its own virtual environment and each has a different WSGI file.

Let I am using a domain name - example.com and three projects project1,project2,project3 so I want to host them like-

`example.com/project1` - It will refer to project1

`example.com/project2` -  It will refer to project2

`example.com/project3` - It will refer to project3

I have kept these projects in htdocs of apache.

```
httpd-vhosts.py
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apache24/htdocs/mainApp/project1/src/src/wsgi_windows.py"
    Alias /static "C:/Apache24/htdocs/mainApp/project1/Research/src/static"

    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/mainApp/project1/src/src/">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/mainApp/project1/src/static">
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

Same code I have written for project2 by replacing project1 to project2 but it's working for project1 but not for project2

This is my configuration file to create virtual hosts

Comment: Did you added the project2 directory?

Comment: Yes i have placed both directories into htdocs of apache